# How to keep Bluetooth Tethering enabled on LineageOS / how to enable it with Tasker on Moto G 2 LTE?

Tags: tasker, bluetooth-tethering

I need to share wifi connection from my Moto to iPhone over Bluetooth with minimal or no manual interaction on Moto G.

How can I make Bluetooth Tethering always enabled (On) at a LineageOS 14.1 device?

Alternatively, how can I setup Tasker script to enable Bluetooth tethering on Moto G 2nd gen LTE (XT1079), running LineageOS 14.1 (build 20170922)?

Comment: See if this helps: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2574310

Answer (score 1):

[Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate&referrer=utm_source%3Dreddit) can do so using its [Bluetooth tethering set state block](http://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/bluetooth_tether_set_state.html), no additional plug-ins required.

Comment: Thanks, it just works! And Automate's in-app search across user-submitted recipes is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Additional requirements:

- [Secure Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intangibleobject.securesettings.plugin)

  **Task**
- Go to the Task tab and select **"New Task + "**
- You can name this Task *AutoBluetoothTether* or anything.
- Click **"+"** to add new Action
- Plugin  → Secure Settins → [Configuration: Actions → BT Tether] → On (Tick *Automatically Enable Bluettooth* option)

Be sure to pair your Android device with Iphone (via bluetooth) prior and also you can set your profile to react to wi-fi connection i.e State → Wi-fi Connected (set SSID)

Comment: Tasker lists "BT Tether" as disabled option. When trying to enable it in Secure Settings, it says "This feature requires a Bluetooth tetherable interface.

Answer (score 0):

> The Automate block doesn't work on my device (Android 8.0, MIUI 9). And the Tasker solution requires a non-free plugin Secure Setting.

Run this(root required) to enable bluetooth tethering:

`service call connectivity 24 i32 2 null i32 0`

It calls [startTethering()](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/e80b45506501815061b079dcb10bf87443bd385d/core/java/android/net/IConnectivityManager.aidl#L80), while `24` represents `startTethering` and `2` represents `TETHERING_BLUETOOTH`.

Tested on Android 8.0. You can check the interface definition(aidl) for your version if it didn't work on older devices.

Comment: Sounds promising. How can I find out "the interface definition (aidl) for my version"?

Comment: @yurkennis Switch the branch of `platform_frameworks_base`(link above) to your version(e.g. `nougat-release` for Android 7).